# HTACCESS -> / returns to 404 and without it file not found

Tags: .htaccess

This is the .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
DirectoryIndex index.php

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php80” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php80 .php .php8 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

`example.com/en/existing-page` -> shows existing page
`example.com/en/existing-page/` -> shows 404

`example.com/non-existing-page` -> "file not found" doesn't direct to 404.html page.
`example.com/non-existing-page/` -> directs to 404.html page

I tried `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)/$ RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [L,R=301]` to remove the slash at the end but no changes.